# Show that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\sqrt{p_i} \leq \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$

Tags: probability, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$ be a set of reals such that $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^n \in [0,1]$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i = 1$. Now let $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ be a set of positive real numbers that are bounded.

Show that  $$\max\limits_{p_i\in[0,1];\enspace \sum p_i=1}\enspace \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\sqrt{p_i}\right)  = \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$$

I encountered the expression on the left on a problem relating to multi-armed bandits. I found the expression on the right by running optimizers over $p_i$ values that I ran for small n - say $n < 100$ and random $x_i$ values. Therefore though I don't have a proof of the above expression, I have reason to believe the expression is true.

I don't know how to start solving the problem. The only similar problem I've looked at relates to *minimizing* $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i^2 x_i$ over all possible $p_i$ values such that $\sum p_i = 1$ and $p_i \in [0,1]$ (Problem No 4 in [Mathematical Tapas, Volume 1](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/mathematical-tapas-volume-1))

It would be very useful to me if you could help me prove the above, or point me to references that would have such a result.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: The expression on the right is $||x||\cdot ||\sqrt{p}||$, and the one of the left is $x\cdot \sqrt{p}$? Nice answer, thanks a lot! Wasn't thinking of them as vectors for some reason.

Comment: It is not obvious at all. I just happen to saw it instantly since it is a trick I saw plenty in my PhD in probability, where one would obtain matrix inequalities by using exactly square roots of probabilities as weights in the CS inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote in my comments Cauchy-Schwarz. Apply it to the vectors $x$ with entries $x_i$ and $y$ with entries $y_i = \sqrt{p_i}.$ Then, $y^\intercal x \leq \|y\|^2\|x\|^2.$ It is exactly what you want once you expand. If you want to attain equality, set $x = y.$

Comment: For equality, you should set $x = ky$ for some constant $k$, not $x = y$.

Comment: $ky$ does not satisfy the assumption that its norm equals one.

Comment: Your condition for equality says that $\|x\| = \|y\| = 1$, which need not necessarily hold. If all the $p_i$ are $1/n$, then having all $x_i = 1$ would satisfy equality as well, but in that case $\sqrt{n} = \|x\| \ne \|y\| = 1$. Am I missing something?